# Calculating total fallout on an area when I have fallout (per unit area) in a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm a total newbie to GIS (QGIS). I have some fallout data in a vector layer (I think...) that I have managed to open. I have also managed to create a new shape file where I have drawn a polygon over my area of interest. (See attached image.)

Since my fallout data is given in units of mass/area, I figured it would probably be easy to somehow calculate the total fallout on my created polygon (i.e. in units of mass). But I can't seem to find out exactly how to do this.

Is this something someone could explain how to do?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to use [`$area`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=area#area) and multiply the outcome with the fallout?